# Easiest way to display array of values in table in windows form C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have an array(rows) of arrays which contains 4 elements which I would like to display in a grid or table in a Windows form in C#.

What is the most straightforward way to accomplish this? Is there a way to bind a data grid to an array (or object perhaps)?

What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [DataGridView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

Instead of an array of arrays, you should make a class with four properties, then make a `BindingList<T>` of that class.

Answer (score 1):

as SLaks said, that is a more structured way of doing it,
here is a way that uses Linq + Anonymous Types to do something similar on the fly:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var evens = from n in numbers select new { Digit = n, Even = (n % 2 == 0) } ;
dataGridView1.DataSource = evens.ToList();
```

Also if you are after nice ways of displaying then have a look at WPF beats Windows Form hands down.